# Class getting parameter from Game.cs

Tags: c#, xna

I am writing a short program. What I need is that I want to set "correct" parameter in Game.cs, and in my advTry.cs, I want to use this "correct" parameter to determine the output.  with my class advTry.cs like:

```
public bool correct { get; set; }

if (correct)
{
    solveButton = new MenuButton(contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("solve"),
      buttonCenter, GameState.AnswerNo);
   Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
else
{
    solveButton2 = new MenuButton(contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("solve"),
                  buttonCenter, GameState.AnswerYes);
    Console.WriteLine("Not OK");
}
```

While in my GAME.cs, I define correct as:

```
if (messageString == "18")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main OK");
    advTry.correct = true;
}
else
{
    advTry.correct = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Main not OK");
}
```

I use the Console.WriteLine to check the passing of boolean parameter "correct". While the result is originally "Not OK", then when I start to input "18", it gives out"Main not OK" first, then "Main OK" (easy to understand, because input"1" then "8").

However, the biggest problem is "OK" never comes out, the state "GameState.AnswerNo" can't be fulfilled, Why is that please? How to fix it please?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for reminding. Will do it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not at all clear. You haven't given any idea of the structure of the code apart from those two conditionals. It's just impossible to answer right now. However, my best guess from what you've written here is that you've set the value of "correct" to true in your advTry class, but you haven't run the code inside that class to output OK to the console. That code won't run automatically just because you set the value of "correct". You need to do something like this in advTry.cs:

```
private bool _correct;
public bool correct  
{
    get { return _correct; }
    set 
    {
        _correct = value;
        output();
    }
}
private void output
{
    if (_correct)
    {
       //output "OK"
    }
    else
    {
       //output "Not OK"
    }
}
```

Comment: Or even use a SetCorrect(bool) method, as setters should do nothing beyond set variables (generally used to set multiple things at once, otherwise a setter wouldn't be needed at all).

Comment: Hello all. Thanks for all your reply. Sorry about the confusion. What I need is that I want to set "correct" parameter in Game.cs, and in my advTry.cs, I want to use this "correct" parameter to determine the output. May I ask that why many people use _correct by putting _ in the front please?

Comment: The underscore is a just a convention that is used to indicate that the variable is private. So you have a public property 'correct' with a getter, and a setter which sets the value of the private variable _correct. Did you try the code? If you change advTry.cs as suggested and leave Game.cs as it is, you should see the output you're looking for.